# unable to import google play services project

Tags: android, admob

I want to integrate new admob with my project, for that I have to import google play service lib in my workspace. But the problem is that I am not able to import it from sdk. I tried all possible solution from this site but still I am not getting it. Please help me out.

Comment: do you have updated sdk,google play service lib?what error exactly you getting?

Comment: import>Android>Existing Android code...>YOUR_SDK\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib check `copy project into workspace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please download admob sdk for android using below link

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

if you are using eclipse please import this sdk in your project and add as a library project in your main project and then please follow bellow link to integrate admob with your project.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android